# Image not uploading to database

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I have created a php script with a form that it should insert some data into database, it actually add the text and the ID but it does not add the file.

the database looks like this:

Database name:  highmob_comenzi
table name: players
in table we got 3 rows:
ID (auto_increment)
name (the name that we insert from the form)
schite (where the files should be uploaded) Type: blob Colation: none , all none

this is the script what I have tried so far

```
 <?php
 include('connect-db.php');
 ?>
 <?php
 function renderForm($name, $schita, $error)
 {
 ?>

 <?php
 if ($error != '')
 {
 echo '<div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red;">'.$error.'</div>';
 }
 ?>
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>"/>
  <input type="file" id="schita" name="schita" >
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Add Data</button>
  </form>
 <?php
 }
 include('connect-db.php');
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
 $name = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
 $schita = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['schita']));
 if ($name == '')
 {
 $error = 'Error !!';
 renderForm($name, $schita, $error);
 }
 else
 {
 mysql_query("INSERT players SET name='$name', schita='$schita'")
 or die(mysql_error());
 header("Location: mobila.php");
 }
 }
 else
 {
 renderForm('','','','','');
 }
 ?>
```

This script creates a page for each ID when we insert data in the form
Like pagename.php?id=4

I want when i fill the form after he create the page when i open the page to see the uploaded file only on that page,

any idea why its not working?

Comment: Tried searching for how to upload a file with php?  Please don't be lazy

Comment: where is the file handling code to process the upload?

Comment: I have searched over the internet, i saw that database should be blob, the file that process the upload isnt the sql.query insert players set schita=$schita ?

Comment: http://makitweb.com/upload-and-store-an-image-in-the-database-with-php/ This might help you.

Comment: if I use the tutorial what you sent it here, i already have a ID row in table, this tut show me to add another one, wich is imposible, the php script that i use he already create a page using id increment

Answer (score 0):

Get the request file using `$_FILES`, also you need to confirm your mysql field (schita) is a `blob` type

Comment: the MySQL field is a blob, i allread checked it, about the $_FILES request i got no idea how to insert it!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct insert query. You are missing 'into' keyword. Change query to:

```
mysql_query("INSERT into players SET name='$name', schita='$schita'");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert image to base64 and then save it to Database.

```
// Select file type
  $target_file = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]); 
  $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

  // Convert to base64 
  $image_base64 = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['schita']['tmp_name']) );
  $image = 'data:image/'.$imageFileType.';base64,'.$image_base64;

  // Insert record
  $query = "INSERT into players(schita) values('".$image."')";
  mysqli_query($con,$query);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to upload the file using this script

```
 <?php
 $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=highmob_comenzi", "highmob", "PW");
 if(isset($_POST['btns'])){
     $name = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
     $type = $_FILES['myfile']['type'];
     $data = file_get_contents($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']);
     $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE players SET data='$myfile', name='$name', mime='$type' WHERE id='$id'");
     $stmt->bindParam(1,$name);
     $stmt->bindParam(2,$type);
     $stmt->bindParam(3,$data);
     $stmt->execute();
 }
 ?>
 <!-- form -->
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="myfile"/>
 <button name="btns"> Incarca Schita </button>
 </form>
 <!-- display data -->
 <?php
 $stat = $dbh->prepare("select * from players");
 $stat->execute();
 while($row = $stat->fetch()){
     echo "<a target='_blank' href='viewschita.php?id=".$row['id']."'>".$row['name']."</a>";
 }

 ?>
```

The problem is i got no idea how to make a link to the file, any idea how?